# Returning Value From Row Selected

Tags: c#, xamarin

My current TableView is returning five items.
Items: Apple, Pear, Banana, Orange, Mango

I'm wondering how do I grab the value of the selected row. For example, If I click on Apple, the value will be "Apple"

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    HelloViewController helloView = new HelloViewController(___________);
    AppDelegate appDelegate = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;
    appDelegate.RootNavigationController.PushViewController(helloView, true);
}
```

where there's an underscore, I would like to display the method to grab the Value. Something like GetRowValue(indexPath). Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your underlying datasource is

```
List<Fruit> data;
```

then in your RowSelected method you use the indexPath to get the selected item:

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var item = data[indexPath.Row];

    HelloViewController helloView = new HelloViewController(item);
    AppDelegate appDelegate = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;
    appDelegate.RootNavigationController.PushViewController(helloView, true);
}
```